# How to factor $4x^2 + 2x + 1$?

Tags: complex-numbers, factoring

I want to know how to factor $4x^2 + 2x + 1$? I found the roots using quadratic equation and got $-1 + \sqrt{-3}$ and $-1 - \sqrt{-3}$, so I thought the factors would be $(x - (-1 + \sqrt{-3}))$ and $(x - (-1 - \sqrt{-3}))$
However, according to MIT's course notes, the factors are $(1 - (-1 + \sqrt{-3})x)$ and $(1 - (-1 - \sqrt{-3})x)$

[Course Notes (pg. 30)](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-01sc-introduction-to-electrical-engineering-and-computer-science-i-spring-2011/unit-2-signals-and-systems/characterizing-system-performance/MIT6_01SCS11_chap05.pdf)

Are these two expressions equivalent, or am I simply not factoring correctly? Thanks.

Comment: With your factorization the coefficient of $x^2$ will be $1$ and not $4$.

Comment: remember that your $x^2$ coefficient is $4$ and your constant is $1$, not the other way around...so $(x-a)(x-b)$ you give you a coefficient of $1$, not $4$ for the $x^2$ term.  You are not factoring correctly.

Comment: The roots you have found are not correct -- there is a missing factor of $1/4$.  However, if those had been the correct roots, your factorization would be correct as well.

Comment: Okay, I know what I did wrong, however I don't see how the answer I get now is equivalent to that given in the course notes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is $\frac{-1 \pm \sqrt {-3}}{4}$ (suppose we know what we mean here by $\sqrt{-3}$).

Then the expansion would be

$\begin{align*}
&4x^2+2x+1=4\left(x-\frac{-1+ \sqrt {-3}}{4}\right)\left(x-\frac{-1- \sqrt {-3}}{4}\right)\\
& = 4\left(x-\frac{1}{-1- \sqrt {-3}}\right)\left(x-\frac{1}{-1+ \sqrt {-3}}\right)\\
&=[-1+(-1- \sqrt {-3})x][-1+(-1+ \sqrt {-3})x] \\
&=[1-(-1- \sqrt {-3})x][1-(-1+ \sqrt {-3})x]
\end{align*}$
 as written in the lecture note.

Note that here we've used the fact that $(-1+ \sqrt {-3})(-1- \sqrt {-3})=4$.

(Thus $\frac{-1+ \sqrt {-3}}{4}=\frac{1}{-1- \sqrt {-3}}$

And

$\frac{-1- \sqrt {-3}}{4}=\frac{1}{-1+\sqrt {-3}}$)

Comment: Thank you! Only answer that showed how to derive the factors from the course notes, I doubt I would have thought of factoring 4 like that myself.

Answer (score 2):

$$4x^2+2x+1$$
Finding roots by quadratic rule as follows 
$$x=\frac{-2\pm\sqrt{2^2-4(4)(1)}}{2(4)}$$ $$=\frac{-2\pm2i\sqrt{3}}{8}$$
$$=-\frac{1}{4}\pm\frac{i\sqrt 3}{4}$$
$$x=-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{i\sqrt 3}{4}\ \vee\ x=-\frac{1}{4}-\frac{i\sqrt 3}{4}$$
**Edit**:

> Now, we have the factors as follows $$4x^2+2x+1=4\left(x+\frac{1}{4}-\frac{i\sqrt 3}{4}\right)\left(x+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{i\sqrt 3}{4}\right)$$

Comment: I don't think the last line is correct, check the coefficient of $x^2$.

Comment: I find everything is OK. Could you please re-check if you don't mind?

Comment: The last line factorization assumes a monic polynomial...but the problem is not...

Comment: Ah, I see that now, however I still don't see how this is equivalent to the answer given in the course notes?

Comment: The last line is not correct @HarishChandraRajpoot , you need a factor of $4$ on the right hand side.

Comment: Oh, yes, you are right

Comment: @HarishChandraRajpoot I think you must have re-edited your post without labeling as “edited”. Such act may cause confusion to others thinking that commenter(s) were making non-sense accusations.

Comment: @Mick: Yes, you are right

Comment: @HarishChandraRajpoot Glad to see that you are making a fast response.

Answer (score 1):

Given $$\displaystyle 4x^2+2x+1 = \underbrace{(2x)^2+1^2+\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2}+1-\underbrace{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2}$$

So we get $$\displaystyle \left(2x+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2-\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}i}{2}\right)^2 = \left(2x+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}i}{2}\right)\cdot \left(2x+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{3}i}{2}\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

> $$4x^2+2x+1=3x^2+(x+1)^2=(\sqrt3x+i(x+1))(\sqrt3x-i(x+1))$$

Answer (score 0):

You could always check if they are the same by multiplying out the course notes's solution.  Start by writing the proposed solution
$$(1-(-1+\sqrt{-3})x)(1-(-1-\sqrt{-3})x)$$
as
$$( (1+x) - \sqrt{-3}x ) ( (1 + x) + \sqrt{-3}x )$$
(this just involves some regrouping).  Now this has the form $(A - B)(A + B)$, so we can immediately rewrite it as
$$(1+x)^2 - (-3)x^2$$
which, on expanding, gives
$$1 + 2x + x^2 + 3x^2$$
which is indeed the original problem.

Having said that, it is also the case that the way the Notes have the solution written is not standard, and I am not sure why they prefer to do it this way.